# SwiftUI: List view vs ForEach view

Tags: swift, xcode, types, foreach, swiftui

The following code essentially determines if it should show a list of hourly-paying jobs or other jobs, and then returns a view based on that. The issue that I am having is that if I replace the **List** views with **ForEach** views, I get the error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

From my research, it seems like this is an error having to do with types. However, this is why I wrapped it in a group. So, why does a list view not produce errors, but the ForEach view does?

```
    func jobList(_ jobListMode: String) -> some View {
        
        Group {
            switch jobListMode {
            case "Hourly":
                List(hourlyJobs, id: \.id) { job in
                    Text(job.jobTitle)
                }
            default:
                List(hourlyJobs, id: \.id) { job in
                    Text(job.jobTitle)
                }
            }
        }
```

this does not produce errors ^^^

```
    func jobList(_ jobListMode: String) -> some View {
        
        Group {
            switch jobListMode {
            case "Hourly":
                ForEach(hourlyJobs) { job in
                    Text(job.jobTitle)
                }
            default:
                ForEach(hourlyJobs) { job in
                    Text(job.jobTitle)
                }
            }
        }
```

this produces the error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

sorry for the long question!

Comment: Try `ForEach(hourlyJobs, id: \.self)` (ForEach also needs each element to conform to `Identifiable`)

Comment: Also can you show code for `hourlyJobs` and `Job`?

Comment: Np! I also added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

SwiftUI is infamous for giving out unhelpful errors like this. Usually the best way to debug is to comment out / delete lines of code until it gives you a more helpful message. But anyway, the reason you're getting this error is because of these lines:

```
ForEach(hourlyJobs) { job in
ForEach(careerJobs) { job in
ForEach(otherJobs) { job in
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach):

> Either the collection’s elements must conform to Identifiable **or** you need to provide an id parameter to the ForEach initializer.

Well, you're not passing in the `id` parameter in any of the above 3 lines. That means each element in your `hourlyJobs`/`careerJobs`/`otherJobs` array must conform to [`Identifiable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable) - and because they don't, you get the error.

So you have 2 options:

1. Pass in the `id` parameter

SwiftUI will then use each element's hash value as its identifier (more details [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-self-work-for-foreach)). However, this isn't ideal, and might result in some weird glitches (especially with animations).

```
ForEach(hourlyJobs, id: \.self) {
ForEach(careerJobs, id: \.self) {
ForEach(otherJobs, id: \.self) {
```

2. Conform your `Job` struct to `Identifiable`

It's simple and works great! Just do:

```
struct Job: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var jobTitle: String
}
```

This satisfies the "the collection’s elements must conform to Identifiable" part of the documentation, so your original code will compile fine.